# MiKTeX won't download ogonek package

Tags: packages, miktex

My MiKTeX won't download the `ogonek` package. I went to the [A-Z list of MiKTeX packages](https://miktex.org/pkg/az), and `ogonek` isn't there. Should it be?

FYI, I know that my MiKTeX automatically downloaded `ogonek` at some point. Then about a month ago I updated my MiKTeX, and apparently `ogonek.sty` disappeared from the "ogonek" folder in the directory to which my MiKTeX automatically downloads packages---the folder was still there, but it was empty. I know that you can get the `\k` accent with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, but that makes some of the fonts look different from the usual Computer Modern; is there another way to get that `\k`?

Comment: You have to install it manually. The package is not in either MiKTeX or TeX Live, as I can see.

Comment: Do you need it in the first place? The package is from 1994 and many things have happened in the last 25 years.

Comment: Is the issue solved? How?

Comment: Not for me at least. I don't know if it's back on the MiKTeX repository.